# MailInaBox config issue (from expiringdict import ExpiringDict)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mailinabox

So i recently upgraded my mailinabox installation and after that when I try to start the mailinabox service I get this error on the console

File "/root/mailinabox/management/auth.py",
from expiringdict import ExpiringDict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'expiringdict'

I have tried and installed the modules manually using pip but it just doesn't work

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you install module in one Python but it runs code with other Pythons. Pythons don't share modules.

Answer (score 0):

Mailinabox has its own library directory. I found out about this by running the following commands:

**# grep -R python3 /root/mailinabox/management/*.py**

/root/mailinabox/management/cli.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/root/mailinabox/management/daemon.py:#!/usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/bin/python3
/root/mailinabox/management/mailconfig.py:# interpreter (/usr/bin/python3) as well as through the

**# head -n1 /root/mailinabox/management/daemon.py**

#!/usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/bin/python3

**# /usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/bin/python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"**

/usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Now, knowing the directory for the mailinbox libraries, you can make symbolic links from the standard directory:

**cd /usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages**

**ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/expiringdict expiringdict**

**ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/expiringdict-1.1.2.egg-info expiringdict-1.1.2.egg-info**

Answer (score 0):

This command should solve the problem

**# /usr/local/lib/mailinabox/env/bin/pip3 install expiringdict**